# Change duplicate value to zero in specific column

Tags: sql

**OBJECTIVE:** to create a Result making duplicate value as zero in PO Amount

[image]

Tables:

`PO` table:

[image]

`Suppliers` table:

[image]

This is what my SQL query so far:

```
SELECT 
    t1.*, t2.* 
FROM 
    PO_Table t1 
LEFT JOIN 
    SI_Table t2 ON t1.[PO Number] = t2.[PO Number]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` here as follows:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.[Posting Date], t1.[PO Number], t1.[Vendor Number], t1.[PO Amount],
           t2.[SI Posting Date], t2.[SI Number], t2.[SI Amount],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.[PO Number]
                              ORDER BY t2.[SI Posting Date]) rn
    FROM PO_Table t1
    LEFT JOIN SI_Table t2
        ON t1.[PO Number] = t2.[PO Number]
)

SELECT [Posting Date], [PO Number], [Vendor Number],
       CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN [PO Amount] ELSE 0.0 END AS [PO Amount],
       [SI Posting Date], [SI Number], [SI Amount]
FROM cte
ORDER BY [PO Number], [SI Posting Date];
```